# acumatica How can I display the Note content when I hover over the Note icon in the grid

Tags: acumatica

I'm want to display the note content every time I  hover over the Note icon displayed in a grid.

For instance; the Service Tab in the Service Screen (FS300100), have a Note Icon that I would like to quick view the text in that Note when I hover over it, so I would  not have the need to open Note to read the content.

Any suggestion and help will be appreciated.
Thanks,

Alfredo

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's not possible out of the box. Hover functionality is a bad fit for a web system using on-demand paging. The note is fetched from the web server only when user opens the popup and there's a noticeable delay to fetch the note record. I don't think the system supports dynamic multiline Tooltip either. The best approach I can think of is to add another custom field which contains the note content.

Comment: Thanks for the answer